# PHP: Использовать переменную как тип для приведения к нужному типу

Tags: php, php7

Нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
$type = 'double';
$text = '0.90000000000002';
$double = ($type)$text;
```

Т.е. тип, к которому будет приведена переменная, зависит от $type.

И нет, я не хотел бы использовать if/switch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `bool settype(mixed &$var, string $type)`

```
$type = 'double';
$text = '0.90000000000002';
settype($text, $type);
```

Comment: `settype` всегда возвращает bool. Переменная передается по ссылке и таким образом меняется ее тип.

Comment: @newman, да-да, поздно уже, просто подставил, сейчас понял, что чушь написал.

Answer (score 0):

Как преобразование типов вероятней всего не получится. Но можно попробовать использовать функции `*val`

```
$type = 'double';
$text = '0.90000000000002';
$func = $type . "val";
$double = $func($text);
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, вот только stringval нет :)

Comment: @user64675, а чем вам [strval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strval.php) не угодил? Т.е. тип был бы `$type = 'str';`

Comment: @user64675 думал над этим. Для такого случая можно свою функцию написать.